# How to set Google Charts legend width in JavaScript?

Tags: google-visualization

I am generating this Google Line Chart using the Google JS API. As you can see, the labels are very narrow. How do I make it so that the whole label text is visible?

[image]

Comment: Could you include sample code? The example at http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization shows far more text in the annotations without it being clipped.

Comment: @Bernhard Hoffman: Which example are you referring to?

Comment: They put way too much time into making the sample charts look good and forgot about basic features like some legend and axis options (this + integer y-axis for example)...Also, the API isn't the most intuitive one I've used.

Comment: I ended up using HighCharts - they cost a bit, but they're worth every dollar because they save you a lot of development time

Comment: Hi there. I'm looking for a graph that looks like the one shown in the image. Where can i find it ? This link doesn't have curved line chart with dotted points : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: @chosenOneThabs: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points

Comment: Thank you very much F.ardelian, i found it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here are some samples based on the [google code playground line charts](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart). Adjusting the chartArea width option gives more space for labels:

```
new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                width: 500, height: 400,
                vAxis: {maxValue: 10},
                chartArea: {width: '50%'}}
        );
```

If it's an option, you could also position the labels beneath the chart, which gives considerably more space:

```
new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                width: 500, height: 400,
                vAxis: {maxValue: 10},
                legend: 'bottom'}
        );
```

Comment: I've found this work-around myself. I hoped for a property which could be used to set the legend width. If there won't be any answers over the weekend, I'll mark this one as correct.

Comment: The legend seems to be included in the chart area. Making the chart area smaller leaves even less room for the legend.

Comment: The config options for line chart say that chartArea should represent where the chart itself is drawn excluding axis and legends, but I could be misinterpreting this. The code playground sample seems to work as expected for me. What output are you noticing?

Comment: I adjusted with `chartArea: {width: '75%'}`

Comment: To get the chart to take up the full space, you may need to set chartArea.left. For example, to give the legend approximately 15% `chartArea: {left:"5%", width:"80%"}` Note: the vAxis labels aren't included in the chartArea so make sure you give enough space for that text

Answer (score 21):

Expanding the chartArea option to a width of 100% solved the problem for me. Contrary to the documentation, the chartArea does include the legend. I used a PieChart but the same option is available for the LineChart.

```
var options = {'title':title,'width':w,'height':h,'chartArea':{left:0,top:10,width:"100%"}};
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(chartDiv));
chart.draw(data,options);
```

[Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html#Configuration_Options).

Answer (score 6):

None of the previous answers worked well for me. Setting *width* to less than 100% centers the plot area and leaves too much unused space on the left. Setting it to 100% is not a solution either.

What worked well - **[see live working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cristiscu/2c28j2n3/2/)** - is setting the ***right*** value to accommodate the legend, then adjusting the ***left*** value eventually, for the Y axis title and labels. The plot area *width* will adjust automatically between these two fixed margins:

```
var options = {
   ...
   legend: { position: 'right' },
   chartArea: {
      right: 130,   // set this to adjust the legend width
      left: 60,     // set this eventually, to adjust the left margin
   },
   ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an option in `legend.textStyle` we can customize legend text styles inside google charts

```
var options = {
                legend: { textStyle: { fontSize: 78  //size of the legend 
                } }
              }
```

Comment: The `legend.textStyle` property doesn't provide a solution to the question. See here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the chart wider or your labels shorter.

Comment: Yeah... I thought of that, but I've made my chart 1000px wide (totally unacceptable) but the labels still don't fit.

Comment: Might also help if he made the Y-axis values smaller. Use kb/sec or mb/sec.