# Google pie chart - move legend to a different location

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How do I put the legend in different place? I dont want to use the legend the in default place in Google pie chart. Here is my code:

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);
```

i want it like this:

[image]

I like to make legend like in image not default legend

Comment: if i can change these data then i can apply as it to my site..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292874/formating-legend-and-axis-in-google-charts

Comment: i need like this https://app.icontact.com/icp/core/track/message/21066?token=30dd1756ba87fc1086087330eaa6f5c8

Comment: i want to make different then default legend.

Comment: please send screenshot it's telling me to log in

Comment: i do not want only change the position but its size

Comment: i tried but this site dont allow me due to less rep. i will send u in mail ok .

Comment: Good edit of the screenshot, @RachelGallen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the width, just adjust the 'width' property in the graph. I don't think multi-column legends are supported in Google charts unfortunately unless you use the [Controls/Dashboards](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) feature or alternatively you could use [Tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) - that way you won't have a legend, the information would just appear when you hover over it.