# Legend items overlap in png

Tags: google-visualization

I need to insert a chart as an image. 
I generated the corresponding chart below. I created the png using `getImageURI`. 
But on the png legend, the item is overlapped. 
How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: What all legend you have, any examples?

Comment: For a lengthy legend, I used `legend.position: right`. But it depends on use-case, you might want to play around with: `legend.position`,  `legend.textStyle.fontSize`, `legend.maxLines`

Comment: I need `legend.position: 'bottom'`. So, I need dynamic width for legend's items.

Comment: @KhatamNaayak F.ex. 3 items: Unbundling, Double billing, Overcharges.  need to show them below chart.

Comment: Referring this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869967/how-to-set-google-charts-legend-width-in-javascript. Use chart area to get more space for your legends.

Comment: @KhatamNaayak The solution for `legend.position: 'right'`. It does not help i my case. Items still have fixed width and overlap each other.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, keep `legend.position: bottom` as you wish and try changing chart area, it changes the available width for legend values.

Comment: It is clear, i checked it. In case bottom chart area not change width legend at all.

Comment: this can occur when the chart is drawn in a hidden container, could that be the case here? check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613423/5090771)...

Comment: Oh, thank you. Looks like you are correct. I just create virtual div for this. `document.createElement('div');`