# icCube: cutted labels in ic3Table and charts

Tags: iccube

in the ic3Table widgets and the charts the labels are cut off. 
we want to be able to show our icCube end-users the whole labels without cutting them.

what should we do to prevent the cutting of the labels ?
is there any global configuration to do this, which works for all reports?
[image: the headers of the table are cutted]

[the legends of chart are cutted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vYyy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the pivot table you can adjust the "Column width" (this is a comma separated list of numbers):

[image: pivot table column width]

As for the charts, I cannot reproduce: which version of the Reporting are you using?

[Edit] this is about Google chart and not AmCharts. That question might help solve the issue by adjusting the chart width and left: [How to set Google Charts legend width in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869967/how-to-set-google-charts-legend-width-in-javascript)

Comment: th version of the reporting we are using is: v7.0.1

Comment: Can you try with the latest version to check if the issue is still there?

Comment: we dit try the new reporting version v7.3, but it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: please contact icCube support.